# Trouble downloading & parsing Google Trends from a JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, jquery

I found this URL that gives you a google trends json file:

http://www.google.com/trends/fetchComponent?cid=TIMESERIES_GRAPH_0&export=3&q=javascript&geo=US
<- This trends link shows you the US search trends history for the word javascript.

I am having trouble parsing it and turning it into an object that I can use. Now I am starting to doubt it's even possible since it's not really an API but instead a raw file.

I had a friend help me build a quick test but doesn't its not working either.

**End Result Goal:**

I just want to be able to pull in all the data via json, have javascript parse it and print the data in the console

Here is the code

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>

    var url = 'http://www.google.com/trends/fetchComponent?cid=TIMESERIES_GRAPH_0&export=3&q=bread&cat&geo=US';

    var jsonObject;

    var google = {
      visualization : {
        Query : {
          setResponse: function(json) {
            jsonObject = json;
          }
        }
      }
    };

    console.log('Making ajax request ...');
    $.ajax({ dataType: 'text', url: url })

      // When it arrives, pull out the JSON using the function we setup on
      // line 16
      .done(function(data) {
        console.log('Data has arrived! Executing it to get the JSON from it ...');
        eval(data);
        console.log(jsonObject);
      })

      // If the request fails, print out the reason why.
      .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        console.log("The ajax request failed: " + textStatus );
      });

  </script>
</body>
```

Thank you!!!

-Nico

Comment: the URL is a piece of javascript which you can run to get the values. You can either use it as is, or you can parse it and just grab the data. This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7805711/javascript-json-google-trends-api

Comment: Thanks Kennypu! I'm going to dig into that, but can you point me in the right direction on how to run a url that is a piece of javascript. I tried creating and object from it and pulling it also using $.get but cant get it working an not sure of the terminology to look up. Thanks again!

Comment: the link provided gives you an example